# "gulp sass" command runs but nothing happens

Tags: sass, gulp

This is my gulpfile.js file;

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function () {
    return gulp.src('./sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'));
});

gulp.task('sass:watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./sass/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

You can see my folders here:

[image: folders]

I write some code in my main scss file and then run gulp sass command in the terminal. It looks like it works but nothing changes.

Comment: Your _main.scss file is a partial, so it will not be converted into anything.  Remove the _ underscore before the filename and it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont think you need the './' in your src directory or destination directory,  should look like this.

```
gulp.task('sass', function () {
return gulp.src('sass/*.scss')
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('css'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For an explanation of partials, see [partials and imports](https://zurb.com/university/lessons/wrangling-sass-import-files) or [sass language guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide):

> You can create partial Sass files that contain little snippets of CSS that you can include in other Sass files. This is a great way to modularize your CSS and help keep things easier to maintain. A partial is simply a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @import directive.

And [sass partial tutorial](https://www.quackit.com/sass/tutorial/sass_partials.cfm).  In your case, remove the underscore before the main.scss filename and it will work as you expect.  Into your main.scss you will **import** other partial files (with leading underscores).